# Different outputs for same algorithm in different languages

Tags: java, c, algorithm

Java Source Code:

```
package n1_problem;

/**
 *
 * @author nAwS
 */
public class loop {

    int loop(long i)
    {
        long n=i;
        int count=1;
        while(n>1){
            if(n%2==0){
                n=n/2;
            }
            else{
                n=3*n+1;
            }
            count++;
        }
       return count; 
    }

    int max_cycle(long j,long k){

        int max=-1;
        for(long i=j;i<=k;i++){
            int count=loop(i);
            if(count>max){
                max=count;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }


}


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        loop lp=new loop();
        System.out.println("Max Cycle:"+lp.max_cycle(1,1000000));
    }

}
```

C source code:

```
int main()
{
    long r,h;
    int f=0;
    do 
    {
        printf("Value,r:");
        scanf("%ld",&r);
        printf("Value,h:");
        scanf("%ld",&h);

        f=max_cycle(r,h);
        printf("Max:%d\n",f);

    }while(getch()!='e');
}

int loop(long i)
{
        long n=i;
        int count=1;
        while(n>1)
        {
            if(n%2==0){
                n=n/2;
            }
            else{
                n=3*n+1;
            }
            count++;
        }
       return count; 
    }

    int max_cycle(long j,long k)
    {

        int max=1;
        long i=0;
        for(i=j;i<=k;i++){

            int count=loop(i);
            if(count>max){
                max=count;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

There is no logical difference between this 2 codes for the 3n+1 problem algorithm.Only problem is in C it gives 476 as maximum cycle number where as in java it is 525...why??

Comment: I suspect your code invokes undefined behavior through signed overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java defines the size and representation of integer types, C does not.  In Java, a `long` is a 64-bit 2's complement number.  In C, it is at least 32 bits, perhaps more, and may be signed, unsigned, 1's complement, 2's complement, sign and magnitude, or other.

Did you notice that if you change this line of your Java code

```
long n = i;
```

to this

```
int n = (int)i;
```

That you get the same result as your C code?  Probably you are on a 2's complement machine and your C compiler decided that `long`s are 32 bits.

Comment: At last!..I got it!...using unsigned long it gives the correct result...:)

Answer (score 5):

In most C compilers `long` is generally defined as a 4-byte integer (short for `long int`). In Java, `long` is defined as an 8-byte integer.

You can change your Java code to use `int` for a 4-byte integer, or use `long long` in your c program for an 8-byte integer (I think this was added in C99, it may or may not be available on your compiler).

Comment: true, technically the range is specified, but it really doesn't make much sense to implement it any other way.

Comment: In C, `long`s are not "generally" 4-bytes.  They are *at least 32 bits* and commonly 32 or 64 (e.g. on x86_64-linux-gnu).  In any case if you care about getting the right size of integer, you don't guess at the magically correct number of `long`s to prepend, you use `stdint.h` or an equivalent pre-C99 header.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` code, in method `max_cycle(long j,long k)`, **max** is initialized to **-1** where as in `C` code it is **1**. Just check, if this is causing the logical error.